# How to give color based on third column in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to D3 and following some tutorials and came across the below for the grouped scatter plot.
https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/scatter_grouped.html

In this, I see that they give

```
// Color scale: give me a specie name, I return a color
  var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(["setosa", "versicolor", "virginica" ])
    .range([ "#440154ff", "#21908dff", "#fde725ff"])
```

they assign color based on species .Instead of this I am having year as a category ranging from 1982 to 2019 .

One way is to give the whole domain from 1982 to 2019 and range as each color. But I don't think as a good approach . Is there any way to assign color with a unique color for each year without having the whole range in the domain.Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

```
var color = function(d) { return d.year;},
    color =d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
```

for d3 v4 this would do the trick .